# Displaying contents of ListView in Flutter and displaying image uploaded from gallery

Tags: android-studio, flutter, listview, dart, flutter-layout

I'm fairly new to software dev using Flutter/Dart and I'm currently working on a widget that uses listview to display the information entered by a user. This information is currently stored in a List and for some reason, each time I add new info to the list, only the info at the first index is printed. I'm not actually getting any error message so it's pretty hard to trace it. I've tried debugging it using print statements but it's really not helping me.

The second problem is that when the user chooses a picture from their gallery, it isn't immediately displayed.

How can I fix these things?

```
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'dart:ui';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:mind_matters/shared/loading.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
    import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
    import 'package:path/path.dart';

class EmergencyContacts extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _EmergencyContactsState createState() => _EmergencyContactsState();
}

class _EmergencyContactsState extends State<EmergencyContacts> {
  bool loading = false;
  static bool buttonPressed = true;

  static String emergencyName = "";
  static String emailAddress = "";
  static String phoneNumber = "";
  static File _contactPic;

  static int index = -1;

  Future getPic() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _contactPic = image;
      print('Image path is: $_contactPic');
    });
  }

  Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_contactPic.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_contactPic);
    StorageTaskSnapshot takeSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
  }

  List<EmergencyContact> emergencyContacts = [];

  void createInstanceOfContact() {
    if (emergencyName.isNotEmpty) {
      emergencyContacts.add(EmergencyContact(
          contactPic: _contactPic,
          emergencyName: emergencyName,
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          emailAddress: emailAddress));
    } else if (emergencyName.isEmpty) {
      emergencyContacts.add(EmergencyContact(
          contactPic: null,
          emergencyName: "null",
          phoneNumber: "null",
          emailAddress: "null"));
    }
  }

  void incrementIndex() {
    if (buttonPressed){
      index++;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading
        ? Loading()
        : Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffff696A),
          elevation: 0,
          leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black45),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("    Add emergency contacts",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            gradient: new LinearGradient(
                colors: [const Color(0xffff696A), const Color(0xffca436b)],
                begin: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
                end: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
                stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: 100000,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 10),
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Container(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                      "For your safety, please enter at least 1 phone number "
                                          "and email. "
                                          "It will be used to contact someone if we or "
                                          "someone you're talking to feel you need "
                                          "immediate help.",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: "Poppins",
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        height: 1.2,
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                      )),
                                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                                  new ListView.builder(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                    new CardRow(
                                        emergencyContacts[index]),
                                    itemCount: emergencyContacts.length,
                                  ),
                                  Text("the index here is $index"),
                                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 194,
                                      child: FloatingActionButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _contactPic = null;
                                            emergencyName = "";
                                            emailAddress = "";
                                            phoneNumber = "";
                                          });
                                          showAlertDialog(context);
                                        },
                                        child: Icon(
                                          Icons.add,
                                        ),
                                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        backgroundColor:
                                        const Color(0xffff696A),
                                        mini: true,
                                        elevation: 10,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                                  Container(
                                    width: 106,
                                    child: RaisedButton(
                                      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                          new BorderRadius.circular(
                                              18.0),
                                          side: BorderSide(
                                            color: const Color(0xffff696A),
                                          )),
                                      elevation: 10,
                                      //:todo don't forget on pressed action
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                      },
                                      color: const Color(0xffff696A),
                                      textColor: Colors.white,
                                      child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                        Text("next step".toUpperCase(),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                                      ]),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ])),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Dialog(
            child: Container(
              height: 422,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text("Add Contact",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            color: const Color(0xffff696A),
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          )),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 50,
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffff696A),
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: SizedBox(
                              width: 92,
                              height: 92,
                              child: (_contactPic != null)
                                  ? Image.file(_contactPic, fit: BoxFit.fill)
                                  : Image.network(
                                'IMAGE',
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              )),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 26),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.photo_camera,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            getPic();
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 320,
                        child: Form(
                          //key: _formKey2,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            obscureText: false,
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              setState(() => emergencyName = val);
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.person,
                                ),
                                hintText: "Enter their name/nickname",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "Poppins",
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  height: 1.2,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                )),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Container(
                        width: 320,
                        child: Form(
                          //key: _formKey2,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            obscureText: false,
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              setState(() => emailAddress = val);
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.email,
                                ),
                                hintText: "Enter their email address",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "Poppins",
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  height: 1.2,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                )),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Container(
                        width: 320,
                        child: Form(
                          //key: _formKey2,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            obscureText: false,
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              setState(() => phoneNumber = val);
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.phone,
                                ),
                                hintText: "Enter their phone number",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "Poppins",
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  height: 1.2,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                )),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text("Cancel",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: const Color(0xffff696A),
                                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                                    height: 1.2,
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                  )),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 80),
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text("Add Contact",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: const Color(0xffff696A),
                                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                                    height: 1.2,
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                  )),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                setState(() {
                                  buttonPressed = true;
                                });
                                if (buttonPressed){
                                  createInstanceOfContact();
                                  incrementIndex();
                                }
                                print("the index is $index");
                                print(emergencyContacts[index].contactPic.toString());
                                print(emergencyContacts[index].emergencyName);
                                print(emergencyContacts[index].phoneNumber);
                                print(emergencyContacts[index].emailAddress);

                                Navigator.of(context).pop();

                                print(_contactPic.toString());
                                print(emergencyName);
                                print(emailAddress);
                                print(phoneNumber);
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}

class CardRow extends StatelessWidget {
  static EmergencyContact emergencyContact;
  static File emergencyContactPic = _EmergencyContactsState._contactPic;
  static String emergencyName = _EmergencyContactsState.emergencyName;
  static String emergencyNumber = _EmergencyContactsState.phoneNumber;
  static String emergencyEmail = _EmergencyContactsState.emailAddress;

  CardRow(emergencyContact);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        height: 130,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 24),
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            contactCard,
            contactCardContent,
            contactThumbnail,
            deleteContact,
          ],
        ));
  }

  final contactThumbnail = new Container(
    //margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, left: 270),
    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
    alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
    child: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 46,
        backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF733b67),
        child: ClipOval(
          child: SizedBox(
              width: 82,
              height: 82,
              child: (emergencyContactPic != null)
                  ? Image.file(emergencyContactPic, fit: BoxFit.fill)
                  : Image.network(
                      'IMAGE',
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    )),
        )),
  );

  final contactCard = new Container(
    height: 124,
    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 46),
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: new Color(0xFF733b67),
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8),
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          new BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black12,
            blurRadius: 10,
            offset: new Offset(0, 10),
          )
        ]),
  );

  final deleteContact = new Container(
    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, left: 270),
    child: IconButton(
      icon: new Icon (Icons.delete_sweep,
        size: 30,
      ),
      color: const Color(0xffff696A),
      onPressed: (){
        //todo delete card
      },
    ),
  );

  final contactCardContent = new Container(
    margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(90, 16, 16, 16),
    constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
    child: new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(height: 4.0),
        new Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.person,
                size: 20,
              ),
              new SizedBox(width: 10.0),
              new Text(emergencyName,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                    height: 1.2,
                    fontSize: 14,
                  )),
            ]),
        new SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Row(children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.phone,
            size: 20,
          ),
          new SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Text(emergencyNumber,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontFamily: "Poppins",
                height: 1.2,
                fontSize: 14,
              )),
        ]),
        new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
            height: 2.0,
            width: 18.0,
            color: const Color(0xffff696A)),
        new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.mail,
              size: 20,
            ),
            new SizedBox(width: 10.0),
            new Text(emergencyEmail,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontFamily: "Poppins",
                  height: 1.2,
                  fontSize: 14,
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

class EmergencyContact {
  File contactPic;
  String emergencyName;
  String phoneNumber;
  String emailAddress;

  EmergencyContact(
      {this.contactPic,
      this.emergencyName,
      this.phoneNumber,
      this.emailAddress});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `listView.builder` is not functioning correctly is that you have declared the variables in the `CardRow` Widget and are using those static values instead of the arguments that you have passed. You are passing the arguments, you just aren't using them.

The only change I did here:

```
final EmergencyContact emergencyContact;
  //static File emergencyContactPic = _EmergencyContactsState._contactPic;
  // static String emergencyName = _EmergencyContactsState.emergencyName;
  // static String emergencyNumber = _EmergencyContactsState.phoneNumber;
  // static String emergencyEmail = _EmergencyContactsState.emailAddress;

  CardRow(this.emergencyContact);
```

Here is where I extracted your widgets as methods(just the ones passed in the argument), the reason I did this was that `this` can't be accessed in the *initializers* that you had done. I would recommend you to start using `final` more, and *extracting your Widgets into their own Stateful/Stateless Widgets, or as methods, as I have done below.* It's good practice.

```
child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            contactCard,
            contactCardContent(),
            contactThumbnail(),
            deleteContact,
          ],
        ));


 Container contactThumbnail() {
    return Container(
      //margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, left: 270),
      margin: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
      alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
      child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 46,
          backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF733b67),
          child: ClipOval(
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 82,
                height: 82,
                child: (emergencyContact.contactPic != null)
                    ? Image.file(emergencyContact.contactPic, fit: BoxFit.fill)
                    : Image.network(
                        'IMAGE',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      )),
          )),
    );
  }

 Container contactCardContent() {
    return new Container(
      margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(90, 16, 16, 16),
      constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
      child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(height: 4.0),
          new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  size: 20,
                ),
                new SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                new Text(emergencyContact.emergencyName,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: "Poppins",
                      height: 1.2,
                      fontSize: 14,
                    )),
              ]),
          new SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          Row(children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.phone,
              size: 20,
            ),
            new SizedBox(width: 10.0),
            Text(emergencyContact.phoneNumber,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontFamily: "Poppins",
                  height: 1.2,
                  fontSize: 14,
                )),
          ]),
          new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
              height: 2.0,
              width: 18.0,
              color: const Color(0xffff696A)),
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.mail,
                size: 20,
              ),
              new SizedBox(width: 10.0),
              new Text(emergencyContact.emailAddress,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                    height: 1.2,
                    fontSize: 14,
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

#### Second Problem

For your second problem, the reason you don't see the image being displayed immediately is that the `showDialog` is not being rebuilt. To explicate more on this, the `setState` that is being used in the `showAlertDialog` function belongs to the parent Widget, so, that means that it is only going to be rebuilding what is outside of that particular function. The *showAlertDialog* function *only* gets rebuilt when you first click on it. In order to fix this, we will either have to put the *showDialog* in a *Stateful widget* or use a *StatefulBuilder* (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html)

The *StatefulBuilder* comes with its own *setState* construction, meaning it can now get rebuilt when using setState, resulting in displaying the image immediately. BUT now we have another issue, I see you have the boolean *buttonPressed* in there, that whole setState(boolean) belongs to the parent widget, not the *StatefulBuilder setState*, so now this means that the list will not be displayed after "add contacts" is pressed until it gets rebuilt. We need the setState from the parent, not from the StatefulBuilder. There are many ways to fix this, but I personally think using a callback is one of the best. First, you will need to create a function, like *rebuildWidget* and simply change the state right there. Secondly, pass that function down to *showAlertDialog* as an argument. Thirdly, go ahead and create a final Function and then assign it. Last, simply call it on the onPressed.

```
void rebuildWidget() {
    setState(() {
      buttonPressed = true;
    });
  }


showAlertDialog(
    context, 
    rebuildWidget
 );

showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, myState) {

  final Function() updateParent = myState;

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
        File myPic;
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {
            return Dialog(
              // title: Text("Title of Dialog"),
              child: Container(
                height: 422,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Column(
                      //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text("Add Contact",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              color: const Color(0xffff696A),
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffff696A),
                          child: ClipOval(
                            child: SizedBox(
                                width: 92,
                                height: 92,
                                child: myPic != null
                                    ? Image.file(myPic, fit: BoxFit.fill)
                                    : Image.network(
                                        'IMAGE',
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      )),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 26),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.photo_camera,
                              size: 30,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await getPic();
                              setState(() { // To rebuild this method
                                myPic = _contactPic;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 320,
                          child: Form(
                            //key: _formKey2,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              obscureText: false,
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                setState(() => emergencyName = val);
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.person,
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Enter their name/nickname",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    height: 1.2,
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Container(
                          width: 320,
                          child: Form(
                            //key: _formKey2,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              obscureText: false,
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                setState(() => emailAddress = val);
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.email,
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Enter their email address",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    height: 1.2,
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Container(
                          width: 320,
                          child: Form(
                            //key: _formKey2,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              obscureText: false,
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                setState(() => phoneNumber = val);
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.phone,
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Enter their phone number",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    height: 1.2,
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              FlatButton(
                                child: Text("Cancel",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: const Color(0xffff696A),
                                      fontFamily: "Poppins",
                                      height: 1.2,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                    )),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 80),
                              FlatButton(
                                child: Text("Add Contact",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: const Color(0xffff696A),
                                      fontFamily: "Poppins",
                                      height: 1.2,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                    )),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                 updateParent();

                                  if (buttonPressed) {
                                    createInstanceOfContact();
                                    incrementIndex();
                                  }
                                  print("the index is $index");
                                  print(emergencyContacts[index]
                                      .contactPic
                                      .toString());
                                  print(emergencyContacts[index].emergencyName);
                                  print(emergencyContacts[index].phoneNumber);
                                  print(emergencyContacts[index].emailAddress);

                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();

                                  print(_contactPic.toString());
                                  print(emergencyName);
                                  print(emailAddress);
                                  print(phoneNumber);
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. It works perfectly. Thank you (: I'll definitely start following the advice you gave. Do you by any chance know what causing the delay in displaying the picture after the user has selected it from their gallery?

Comment: thank you so much. This means a lot that you went into depth and explained everything I was doing wrong to me. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, by the way, I meant to write StatefulBuilder NOT StreamBuilder, I corrected it.

Comment: Ah that’s fine(: thank you. By the way, is it possible to please erase my api token from the answer? I didn’t notice it was there till now..

Comment: I have now deleted it, which does not make a difference. I would highly recommend creating a new one because it will still be visible to those that view my edits and yours.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll do that straight away(: